# Login functionality for iOS app giving exception NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I'm creating a login page in XCode for an iOS app. There is a login button on the screen, along with username and password text fields. On clicking the button, the user authentication should be performed and the user should be able to proceed to the next screen. I'm usin the following code:

```
-(IBAction)validateLogin:(id)sender
{  Gusr = @"";
   Gpass = @"";
    const char *dbpath = [mDatabasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mDiary) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                              @"SELECT mPassword FROM USERDETAIL WHERE mUserName=\"%@\"", 
                              mUserName.text]; 
         const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(mDiary, 
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                Gusr =  [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];                    
                Gpass  = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];                    

                  //  NSLog(@"'%@'",Gusr);         
                  //  NSLog(@"'%@'",Gpass);        

                if ([mUserName.text isEqualToString:Gusr] && [Gpass isEqualToString:mPassword.text]){
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
                }else {
                    NSLog(@"not valid");
                }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
            }

            sqlite3_close(mDiary); 

        }   


    }     
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Login"]) {

        // Get destination view
        dashboardViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Get button tag
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

        // Set the selected button in the new view
      //  [vc setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
    }
}
```

On running the build, I'm getting the following exception:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

What exactly is the problem? And even if the exception is fixed, is this code otherwise ok to perform Login successfully?

Comment: where do you define `mDiary` ?

Comment: The exception means (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0) line doesn't return the string . If possible check this NSLog(@"val is %@",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0));

Comment: @Rikkies mDiary has been declared in appViewController. appViewController imports dashboardViewController, which is the scene I need to get to.

Comment: @Tendulkar the exception disappears if I replace mPassword with Password and mUserName with Username. But then the authentication does not work, ie. the user can fill any details in the textfields and login. The name of the fields in the Userdetail table is mUserName for username and mPassword for password. What's the problem?